# Remove Special Characters in R

Tags: r, regex

I have a dataset with columns with names that include a string of special characters ("+/-"). I want to use gsub to replace this string with "plumin" but I can't figure out the regular expression to do it.

Example:

```
names(data) <- gsub("+/-", "plumin", names(data))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can place it inside square bracket to literally evaluate it otherwise the metacharacter meaning of `+` is one or more

```
names(data) <- gsub("[+/-]", "plumin", names(data))
```

If we want to replace the literal string, use `fixed = TRUE` as the default mode is `regex` and th characters (depends) would be evaluated accordingly

```
names(data) <- gsub("+/-", "plumin", names(data), fixed = TRUE)
```

The above will replace each of the `+`, `/` or `-` with "plumin".

But, if the intention is to replace those names with "plumin" having any of these substring, then use `grep` (not recommended to have duplicate names in the data)

```
replace(names(data), grep("[+/-]", names(data), "plumin")
```

Comment: I think you mean `"[+]/-"`. You could also escape the`+` with `\\+`.

Comment: @Mosquite. Yes, it can be escaped, but most of the characters are literally evaluated within the `[]` except for `^`

Comment: `"[+]/-"` worked for me. I want to replace the literal string "+/-" rather than both pluses and minuses.

Comment: @JamesMartherus. I updated the answer.  Hopefully, it works